# Airflow, number of run instances does not match start_date, end_date and interval

Tags: airflow

I am new to airflow, I have set the date as below:

```
start_date=datetime.datetime(2022,7,30,7,33),
end_date=datetime.datetime(2022,7,30,7,35),
schedule_interval='*/1 * * * *'
```

If I run the dag **before** the start_date, I expect to see **3** runs:

first run execute after 2022,7,30,7,34
second run execute after 2022,7,30,7,35
third run execute after 2022,7,30,7,36

However, my dag return **4** runs. The first run happened **immediately** once I clicked start, even though I clicked start well before the start_date.

Shouldn't airflow wait until start_date+interval to execute the first run?